# ASDM 7.20 doesn't work with script that works with ASDM 7.13

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I have a script I wrote for Linux that enables me to use ASDM with Oracle Java 8.  One version I know for sure works is 7.13.1 on an ASA 5516, but when I try the same script with 7.20.1 on an FPR 2110 running ASA software, it fails.  From what I can tell, the URL path for the JNLP has changed, and I have no idea what it should be now.  Does anyone know what the correct URL path for the JNLP is in the new version?

This is the exception it gets once I click "Continue":

```
JNLPException[category: Download Error : Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://10.40.40.1/admin/public/asdm.jnlp : LaunchDesc: null
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://10.40.40.1/admin/public/asdm.jnlp
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1910)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:92)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1504)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1502)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:784)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1501)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.HttpUtils.followRedirects(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.BasicHttpRequest.doGetRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory._buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: I also can't get this working on a Windows VM.  It says the program can't run on Windows 10.  I found a page saying how to fix that -- use wscript.exe included in Windows instead of the one it tries to use -- but that isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working.  On Windows, I had to remove the "start" from the commandline in the `run.bat` file and explicitly tell it to use javaw from Oracle Java 8 instead of the default java version on the VM which was Temurin JDK17.

On Linux, I copied the launcher files from the Windows VM and fixed up the .sh script they included to fix some problems with it.